# Incorrect schema for yaml file using Serverless Framework Configuration - expected a string

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, serverless

I am using serverless framework configuration and aws for the serverless.yml file and also the yaml plugin on VSCode and it says that is incorrect type and is expecting a string.

```js
events:
      - cloudwatchEvent:
          name: ${self:custom.transcribeJobName.${self:provider.stage}}
          event:
            source:
              - 'aws.transcribe'
            detail-type:
              - 'Transcribe Job State Change'
            detail:
              TranscriptionJobStatus:
                - COMPLETED
                - FAILED
```

Comment: confirm if the value of `${self:custom.transcribeJobName.${self:provider.stage}}` is indeed a string type

Comment: the error starts from the line ``source`` till th end

Comment: Is the error displayed by VSCode? If so, I think it's a bug in the extension that doesn't properly recognize serverless variables.

Comment: yes so the error comes from the yaml Red Hat extension, I will check that out as well

Comment: will check out with them as well thank u

Answer (score 0):

The documentation of Serverless Framework no AWS events doesn't list AWS Transcribe at all. I also tried googling but couldn't find any native event for that.

https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events

So can you share which documentation or blog you're following to implement your solution?

Comment: I will update you no probs, I raised tickets on storageSchema and yaml extension. For instance an other error I solved is that the ``!Ref`` tag is not supported yet so it needs to be without the !.

Comment: check this as well: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lalcebo/json-schema/master/serverless/reference.json

Comment: also this is from their website as well: https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/cloudwatch-event

Answer (score 0):

Got this in my feed, the error is coming from serverless json-schema which isn't always up to date since it isn't maintained by the same team.
I've created the PRs for both serverless json schema and for serverless types as well to get this issue sorted out at the source.
It's obviously not thorough and compelete, but the best I cloud do.

https://github.com/lalcebo/json-schema/pull/13
https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/59966

Edit:- schema updated, vscode should stop complaining on restart.

Comment: o my god! thank you very much @Himanshu Pant! you are a star!

Comment: No worries, happy to help. I hope it worked out for you, @types/serverless hasn't been updated yet, so serverless.ts support is still fuzzy.